# Proof related to absolute value

Tags: discrete-mathematics, absolute-value

I was trying to prove

$|x||y| = |x\cdot y|$
but do not have a clue to start. I have seen examples of |x|+|y| >= |x+y| but could not translate it to my problem. Please my fellow math geniuses, help a brother out. Much appreciated

Comment: You can break it into four cases. For example: If x<0, y<0, then |x|*|y|=(-x)(-y) = xy = |xy|.

Comment: what happens if x>= 0  and y<0, this shall complete my proof.

Comment: @user182042 If $x\geq 0$, then $|x|=x$, and since $y<0$, then $|y|=...$ what? Also, think about what the sign of $xy$ is if $x\geq 0$ and $y<0$.

Comment: Or also: $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\Rightarrow |x|\cdot|y|=\sqrt{x^2}\cdot\sqrt{y^2}=\sqrt{x^2\cdot y^2}=|x\cdot y|$

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that if either $x=0$ or $y=0$, then $xy=0$ and $|xy|=0$, but also $|x||y|=0$, so the statement holds. Now, what if both $x$ and $y$ are nonzero?

If $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, then, as David Peterson wrote in his comment, you only have to separate $4$ cases:

- $x>0,y>0$
- $x>0, y<0$
- $x<0, y>0$
- $x<0, y<0$

In each case, proving that $|x||y|=|xy|$ is simple.

If $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, then the easiest way is to write $x=r_1e^{i\phi_1}$ and $y=r_2e^{i\phi_2}$, however, this is not the most basic way. The basic way is to write $x=a+bi$ and $y=c+di$, then using the fact that $|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ to prove that $|xy|=|x||y|$.

Comment: Thank you for your effort but it is still cloudy. I tried |x|*|y|=(-x).y referring to the third case in your comment.but It does not equal to |x.y| .. I am starting to dislike discrete maths :(

Comment: @user182042 Which part is unclear? The real or complex? It is not all written out on purpose, the idea is that you write down these things and figure them out yourself.

Comment: @user182042 In the third case, $|x||y|=(-x)y$, you are correct. But what is $|xy|$? *Hint:* is $xy$ a positive or negative number?

Comment: In that case -(xy) is a negative number.And from the definition of absolute value |x| = x if x>0 and -x if x<0. therefore, -xy  = |xy|. Got it finally. Sometimes you need someone for a little push. Thank You very much bro

Comment: Well, actually, $xy$ is a negative number, so $-(xy)$ is a positive number, but yes, in the third case, $|xy|=-(xy)$.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain what the problem with this answer is? I want to know so I can improve it...

Answer (score 1):

If $x=y=0$, then

$$ |x|\cdot |y| = 0 \cdot 0 = 0 = |0| = |xy| $$

Suppose now $x  >0 $ and $y < 0 $, ($xy < 0$) then

$$ |x| \cdot |y| = x \cdot (-y) = -xy = |xy|$$

Similarly, you can check the case $x < 0$ and $y > 0$. The case $x,y >0$ is proved in the comment to your question.

Comment: I got it finally, I really appreciate it.